# SQL to Linq/Lambda

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, lambda

Anyone can help me how to convert sql statement to linq and lambda like this ?

```
SELECT
    tbl_terms.ID,
    tbl_terms.Terms 
FROM
   tbl_terms
    LEFT JOIN tbl_asn_uploaddoc ON tbl_terms.ID != tbl_asn_uploaddoc.Id_term 
WHERE
    tbl_asn_uploaddoc.Nip = '201948274838491943' && tbl_asn_uploaddoc.STATUS = 1
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: We could, but I'd like to see your efforts first, so I know where you struggle and there for give you a better explanation.

Comment: See my answer below. BTW, what you have written here is neither SQL nor LINQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below query that will give you `LEFT JOIN` on both of your entity,

```
 var result = (from t in _con.tbl_Terms
                      join u in _con.tbl_asn_uploaddocs on t.ID equals u.Id_term
                      into tu
                      where !tu.Any()
                      from u in tu.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      where u.Nip == "201948274838491943" && u.STATUS == 1
                      select new
                      {
                          ID = t.ID,
                          Terms = t.Terms
                      }).ToList();
```

Where `_con` is your context.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'm really appreciate and it almost valid. i want to select data where "t.Id != u.Id_Term" :)

Comment: **Answer updated**, kindly mention this line => `where !tu.Any()` and let me know

Answer (score 1):

LINQ is mostly similar to SQL if you use query syntax instead of method syntax. Here is what I could gather quickly. Can't test because I don't have your model classes.

```
var Result = from t in context.tbl_terms
join d in context.tbl_asn_uploaddoc on t.ID != d.Id_term
where d.Nip = '201948274838491943' && d.STATUS = 1
select t.ID, t.Terms
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be a join?  He wants a left join.

Comment: @dotNet Thanks for your answer, but statement "....on t.ID != d.Id_term" is invalid. :) is it use left join statement ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL to LINQ converter tool [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/)

Linqer is a SQL to LINQ conversion tool. It helps learning LINQ and convert existing SQL statements.